# Returning all children of the div with the select id and selected option using JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to write a JQuery selector that iterates through "publication" div and print all the select tag id's and selected option ids for it. How can I do this ? Here is my html code

```
<div id="publication">
     <div>                        
     <div>                          
         <select class="form-control" id="2001">
            <option value="0">1 Star</option>
            <option value="1" selected >2 Stars</option>
         </select>                        
     </div>
     <div>                          
         <select class="form-control" id="2008">
            <option value="0" selected >1 Star</option>
            <option value="1">2 Stars</option>
         </select>                        
     </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Here is the desired result that I'm seeking.

> ["2001":"1" , "2008":"0"]

**Found a solution:**

```
var str = "";
$("#publication").find( "select" ).each(function(i,e) {
  str += '"'+$(e).attr("id") + ":" + $(this).val() + '" ,';
});    
console.log("{"+str+"}");
```

Comment: Learning DOM interaction [without jQuery](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/) can help you familiarize yourself with how it all works.

Comment: utilize find() and/or children()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the selected options and use the `map` method to get the id of the select and the value of the option in an array.

```
var result = $('option[selected]').map(function(i, e){
  return [[$(e).parent().attr('id'), $(e).val()]];
}).get();
```

The result isn't exactly what you wanted, because that isn't very practical. (Besides, the syntax in your example isn't working, so I'm not sure that I understood your exact intention either.) Instead this gets you:

```
[["2001", "1"], ["2008", "0"]]
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/W5kDL/1/

Comment: What if there is other dropdowns in the page ? I have two div, I want to only get the children of the "publication", any suggestion ?

Comment: @AlexCon: Just put that in the selector: `$('#publication option[selected]')`

Answer (score 0):

This should return the string you're looking for.

```
var form;

form = $("#publication").find(".form-control");

var string_return;

string_return = form.attr("id");
string_return += ":"+form.children("option:selected").val();
```

string_return -> "2001:1"